# Can you switch a relay using 120V AC?

Tags: relay

I'd think that switching a relay with 120V AC at the coils would not work due to this: https://gyazo.com/2a26aab1dbc70d3da16d0e5e31f1e759

Is that correct? If so, does that also mean 48VDC is the max voltage the coils of this relay can handle?

What I'm trying to do is switch on/off a small current using a larger one, so that a microcontroller can detect when it is on or off. Is there a easy/cheap way of doing this? Thank you.

Comment: You power a relay coil with whatever voltage it's been designed to be powered with. That graphic just shows the options available for a particular range of relays and doesn't identify any one relay in particular.

Comment: Well that actually answers my question. So even if 48VDC was the rating for mine, 120VAC would not work. Darn. Need to figure out another way without relays then probably.

Comment: Well, you could just use a relay with a 120V coil instead of that one.

Comment: I'll try to find something like that before buying these: https://www.amazon.com/C-J-design-Current-Sensor-Arduino/dp/B00XT0PL20/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&qid=1491558734&sr=8-4 since these are a bit expensive.

Comment: Well, I found 120V coil relays, but they are quite a bit more expensive than these current sensors I found. Looks like these current sensors are going to be my best bet. Thanks guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a non-contact current sensor like this one (https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11005) that works off the magnetic field created by current in a line.